# Building up a URL in Objective-C

Tags: ios, nsurl

I want to make a request to diffrent servers
I only want to fill in the url or ip address in a textfield. 
I build different solutions but they all faild. I think with this one i'm close.

This is what I build so far:

```
NSString *part0 = @"http://";
NSString *part1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , _serveradres.text ];
NSString *part2 = @"/API/";
NSString *compURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , part0 , part1 , part2 ];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:compURL];



ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Only the address is diffrent, the api's are all ways on the same place.

Later on i want to make a switch that can choose http or https

Comment: Hint: Have a look at `compURL` in the debugger.

Comment: Hint: Don't take the first answer you see.  Look over the answers given and try to understand what each one is describing.  The answers by Augustine P A and myself will have you getting the same result, but with a more efficient solution.  Strive to pick the answers apart and understand what is going on.  Just copying and pasting code is a bad practice without understanding what you are doing.

Comment: I indeed switched to the smaller solution ;) thank you.

Comment: If you changed and are using a different answer, you should mark that one as the correct answer.  This will save others time when finding this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change this:

```
NSString *compURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , part0 , part1 , part2 ];
```

To this:

```
NSString *compURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@" , part0 , part1 , part2 ];
```

Because now your `compURL` would be just `http://`

Hope it helps

Comment: For now i use this one. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 6):

Do like this

```
NSString *compURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/API/", serverAddr];
```

Comment: this works only when I use _serveradres.text

Comment: serverAddr is for your information. you have replace it with "_serveradres.text"

Answer (score 1):

No need for all those instantiated `NSString`'s:

```
NSString *compURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/API/", _serveradres.text]; // Probably ought to be self.serveradres.text instead.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:compURLString];
```

*Note - I changed the name for your pointer to compURL to compURLString.  The habit of naming your variables after what they do AND what they are will save you headache later.

Comment: Thank you this works also, I'm not sure which method is best for me to use

Comment: Read my comment to your question above.  Either my solution or Augustine's is better because you instantiate less NSString objects.  More efficient is almost ALWAYS better :)