# What native class exists for URL building in iOS Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurl

In many frameworks (or core to the language in many modern programming languages) there is some tool for easily building URLs. For instance, suppose you have a schema (`http`), a domain (`www.example.com`), an API base path (`/api/v1/`) and now you want to generate several URLs for different API endpionts:

- `http://www.example.com/api/v1/customers`
- `http://www.example.com/api/v1/customers/1`
- `http://www.example.com/api/v1/orders`
- `http://www.example.com/api/v1/orders/1`
- etc

On Android this can be done using `Uri.Builder`:

```
public MyClass()
{
    this.builder = new Uri.Builder()
                       .scheme("http")
                       .authority("www.exmaple.com")
                       .path("/api/v1/");
}

public void customerList()
{
    request(this.builder.appendPath("customers").build().toString());
}

public void getCustomer(int id)
{
    request(this.builder.appendPath("customers/" + id).build().toString());
}

public void orderList()
{
    request(this.builder.appendPath("orders").build().toString());
}

public void getOrder(int id)
{
    request(this.builder.appendPath("orders/" + id).build().toString());
}
```

What corollary class exists in iOS for this purpose? Some quick Googling wasn't able to find an answer, and all I found on StackOverflow was [[Building up a URL in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437346/building-up-a-url-in-objective-c](this) question) which just uses string formatting. Ideally I would prefer to avoid a string formatting solution since it could break if someone, for instance, typed `www.example.com/` for the domain (with an extra slash), because there's no context and no class validating the input.

I would imagine `NSURL` probably has some functionality like what I'm looking for, but couldn't figure out how to properly utilize it. [Apple's documentation on the class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl#1663756) mentions that a URL possesses a scheme, user, password, host, port, etc (all of the members I would expect from a proper URL builder) but doesn't mention how to set them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`NSURLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlcomponents?language=objc), you can construct URLs from the constituent parts and can convert between `NSURL` and `NSURLComponents` objects.

Comment: Can you provide a code example for using `NSURLComponents`? I just tried something like `NSURLComponents *test = [[NSURLComponents alloc] init]; test.scheme = "https"; test.host = "www.example.com"; NSLog([[test URL] absoluteString]);` and it logged `(null)` - so I must be missing something.

Comment: @stevendesu - What compiler are you using, your code fragment produces a few errors that should be reported. You have C strings rather than Obj-C ones, and `NSLog` should really have a format (without one your URL string is taken as the format and if it has any `%`'s in it...). The fragment `NSURLComponents *test = [[NSURLComponents alloc] init]; test.scheme = @"https"; test.host = @"www.example.com"; NSLog(@"%@", [[test URL] absoluteString]);` works fine.

Comment: Good catch on the C strings. I didn't copy/paste the code but re-typed it since SO comments don't have good formatting, and I often forget my `@` symbols (having to add them later when the compiler complains). The lack of a format string on `NSLog` may have been my issue. I'm very new to Objective-C, so I'm making a lot of newbie mistakes right now. When I'm back at the office Monday I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you're looking for the [NSURL class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl?language=objc), which handles URLs for all Mac platforms. And you use it more or less the same way you do in the Android code:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/api/v1"];
NSURL * urlCust1 = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"customers"];
NSURL * urlCust2 = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"customers/%@",Cid]];
NSURL * urlOrder = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"orders"];
NSURL * urlorderFull = [urlOrder URLByAppendingPathComponent:Oid];
NSURL * basePath = [[url URLByDeletingLastPathComponent] URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

NSURL takes care of the slash delimiters, so you don't need to keep track of those (if you forget it in the string, NSURL will add it; if you have an ending slash in the receiver and a starting slash in the new component, NSURL will squash one of them).